# PHPCS: Strings should have translatable content

Tags: php, wp-cli, coding-standards

I am validating plugin to make it compatible with `WPCS`. a function which contains `gettext` placeholder returning error when i run `phpcs` command. Source code and screenshot of error is attached for reference. Maybe i am missing something or doing it in wrong way?

```
/**
 * Add Error.
 *
 * @package Mypackage
 * @since 0.1.0
 *
 * @param string $code Error Code.
 * @param string $message Error Message.
 * @return object WP_Error Returns Error Object.
 */
function mypackage_add_error( $code, $message ) {

    /* translators: %s: Error Message */
    return new WP_Error( $code, sprintf( esc_html__( '%s', 'mypackage' ), $message ) );
}
```

**Screenshot of Error.**
[image]

Comment: there is nothing to translate on this ligne then the code is the same as doing `return new WP_Error( $code, $message);`

Comment: @mmm Thanks but its supposed to translate error messages. does that make sense or need to wrap message itslef in gettext wrapper while calling `mypackage_add_error`?

Comment: `mypackage_add_error` seems somewhat redundant, would it not be easier to just create the `WP_Error` object in place rather than calling `mypackage_add_error`? `mypackage_add_error` is not the place for translation, and `%s` is not something to be translated

Comment: @TomJNowell actually i was feeling awkward to create instances of `WP_Error` every-time which i am still doing in `mypackage_add_error`. not sure if its good or bad practice but eventually it was supposed to find a nicer way. so instead of calling `WP_Error` directly i wrap it in a function to  easily modify in future. so my point of interest is maybe: can we use dynamic strings from variables with translation functions? just like i do with `$message`  in above function

Comment: Translation functions can't use variables because php is not executed to extract translatable strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code

1. The is no need for translation there. The message should have been translated before it is being passed to that function. At that function there is actually no context at all to create any different translation than `%s`
2. Escaping should happen at the output. You should escape the result of the `sprintf` and the translation.

And keep in mind that WPCS is a tool to help you, not the bible. At least at its current stage it lacks too many feature to just blindly follow it all the time. Some of the errors it emits right now are due to bad parsing of modern PHP or lacking features, so if you are 100% sure that in your specific case `%s` should be translatable go with it.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to translate a placeholder `%s` which is not a translatable content and it'll be replaced with a variable later. It's best to pass the translated `$message` instead of a translatable `$message`.

You should write the function definition this way

```
function mypackage_add_error( $code, $message ) {
    return new WP_Error( $code, $message );
}
```

And the function `mypackage_add_error()` should be used this way

```
mypackage_add_error( 'test-error', esc_html__( 'Test error message', 'text-domain' ) );
```

Comment: Hi @objPlabon, Thank you for your explanation I got to learn and focus on Translatable and Translated content. great explanation

Comment: Great, stay focused and keep learning :)